# MenuItemClick Event Not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `asp:menu`.In this asp menu,on clicking menu item,I want to get the menuitem,and its parent.I tried to use `menuitemclick` event. But `menuitemclick` event is not firing on clicking menu item.Can any body help?

Answer (score 1):

Most times I see an asp.netter claiming that events aren't firing it's usually because they're re-binding the control every postback. For example they don't have:

```
if(!IsPostBack){

    //... Bind control ...

}
```

In the PageLoad event which always fires before command events within controls.

Comment: This was exactly the problem I was having. Thank you so much.